# Is there a site where I can see how much EOS is being unstaked over time?

Tags: stake, unstake

I'm looking for a chart that shows how much EOS is being unstaked over time. Say last week 5 million was being unstaked and then today, there is 10 million being unstaked. Is there a chart for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that anyone has made a chart like this so far. However it shouldn't be too difficult to create such a chart as all you have to do is monitor for the `eosio::undelegate` action using any history solution like `dfuse`.

Comment: i just want to confirm if there was more unstake actions right after Dan Lamier announced he was leaving block one.